# Gtk Widget is not redrawn after window resize

Tags: gtk

I have Gtk.Grid and after resizing window, it does not refresh (event columns and everything is set up correctly), but when you resize it again or click on item, it will redraw.

Gtk.main_iteration() causes segfault in python3

```
from gi.repository import GLib, Gtk

class Grid(Gtk.Grid):
    min_width = 400
    min_height = 300
    min_spacing = 20

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Grid.__init__(self, name='feed_grid',
            row_spacing=20, column_spacing=20)

        self.set_column_homogeneous(True)
        self.set_size_request(self.min_width, self.min_height)

        self.connect('size-allocate', self._on_size_allocate)

        self._cols = 2

    def _on_size_allocate(self, widget, allocation):
        self.set_width(allocation.width)

    def set_width(self, width):
        self._cols = (width + self.min_spacing) // self.min_width
        self._rebuild_grid()

    def get_columns(self):
        return self._cols

    def add_feed(self, feed):
        feed.set_order(len(self.get_children()))
        self._attach_feed(feed)
        feed.show_all()

    def _rebuild_grid(self):
        for feed in self.get_children():
            self.remove(feed)
            self._attach_feed(feed)

    def _attach_feed(self, feed):
        y, x = divmod(feed.get_order(), self.get_columns())
        self.attach(feed, x, y, 1, 1)
```

**Bug report**
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/987565

**Video**
https://launchpadlibrarian.net/102937139/floaty%20resize.ogv

Comment: It appears at startup you'll have `_cols = 2`, but after `_on_size_allocate()`, `_cols` will be at least `20` plus whatever `allocation.width` is -- is this intentional?

Comment: Have you tried using connect_after for 'size-allocate'? I wonder if the default handler needs to be called first.

Comment: @sarnold I know, it is because I do not know size when I am adding widgets to grid, it is default size and it will be definitely not 20+ (only if window width is bigger than 7980px)

Comment: @ergosys I have tried it, it does not help, thanks, for me, it seems like compiz after window resize does not trigger refresh of window

Comment: I have solved it, kinda, I use check-resize event for main window, then get allocation and resize grid